# Cos[sqrt[-x]] == Cosh[sqrt[x]] but not Cos[sqrt[-(x+y)]] == Cosh[sqrt[(x+y)]]?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have trouble with the following apparent contradiction:

```
In[1]:= FullSimplify[Cos[Sqrt[-a]] == Cosh[Sqrt[a]]]
Out[1]= True

In[2]:= FullSimplify[Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]]]
Out[2]= Cos[Sqrt[-b - c]] == Cosh[Sqrt[b + c]]
```

I also tried...

```
In[3]:= FullSimplify[ Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]] /. {b -> a - c}]
Out[3]= True

In[4]:= FullSimplify[Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]], b \[Element] Reals && c \[Element] Reals]
Out[4]= Cos[Sqrt[-b - c]] == Cosh[Sqrt[b + c]]

In[5]:= FullSimplify[Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]], b > 0 && c > 0]
Out[5]= True
```

...but is there a way so resolve this without an explicit substitution or without making assumptions (which weren't necessary for a in the first place)?

(running Mathematica 12.0.0.0 on MS Windows (64-bit))

Comment: g[Power[x_, 1/2]] := -I*Power[-x, 1/2]; Simplify[TrigToExp[Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]]], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g}]

Comment: Works very fast, thank you! Is there a way to modify this for arguments in the form (Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2 + Sqrt[c]] d)/e or in general arbitrary arguments?

Comment: Not quite clear what your mean. Added g[ ] rule is rather general (do not restrict structure of argument of Sqrt[ ], the FullForm of which is Power[_,1/2 ]). You can keep adding as many rules as your want on your own risk. Another very useful option to Simplify family is ComplexityFunction (read in doc).

Comment: For example g[Power[x_, 1/2]] := -I*Power[-x, 1/2]; Simplify[TrigToExp[Cos[Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2 + Sqrt[c]] ] == Cosh[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2 - Sqrt[c]]]], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, g}] does not work.

Comment: sqrtRule = 
  Power[x_, 1/2] :> 
   RuleCondition[-I*Power[-x, 1/2], 
    LeafCount[x] > LeafCount[Expand[-x]]]; Cos[Sqrt[-a^2 + b^2 + Sqrt[c]]] == 
  Cosh[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2 - Sqrt[c]]] /. sqrtRule

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**  ...   (Contrary to first result, true without conditions)

Splitting b and c into real and imaginary part together with Reduce helps to show second equation beeing True.

```
red2 = Reduce[
b1 \[Element] Reals && b2 \[Element] Reals && c1 \[Element] Reals &&
 c2 \[Element] Reals && 
Cos[Sqrt[-(b + c)]] == Cosh[Sqrt[(b + c)]] /. {b -> b1 + I b2, 
c -> c1 + I c2}, {b1, b2, c1, c2}, GeneratedParameters -> d]

(*   ((b1 | b2 | c1 | c2) \[Element] Reals && 
     b2 + c2 != 0) || ((b1 | b2) \[Element] 
Reals && ((c1 > -b1 && c2 == -b2) || (c1 == -b1 && 
   c2 == -b2) || (c1 < -b1 && c2 == -b2))) || (d[1] \[Element] 
Integers && (b1 | b2) \[Element] 
Reals && ((d[1] >= 1 && c1 == -b1 - 4 \[Pi]^2 d[1]^2 && 
   c2 == -b2) || (d[1] >= 0 && 
   c1 == -b1 - \[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Pi]^2 d[1] - 4 \[Pi]^2 d[1]^2 && 
   c2 == -b2)))   *)

FullSimplify[red2, 
b1 \[Element] Reals && b2 \[Element] Reals && c1 \[Element] Reals && 
c2 \[Element] Reals]

(*   True   *)
```

The same can be done for the first equation.

Comment: The output of `Reduce[Cos[Sqrt[-a]] == Cosh[Sqrt[a]], a, Complexes]` is simply wrong.  `Cos[Sqrt[-a]]` and `Cosh[Sqrt[a]]` are identical entire functions (see Order 1/2 in [that Wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)). Their power expansions are identical: execute `Series[Cos[Sqrt[-a]] {a, 0, n}]` and `Series[ Cosh[Sqrt[a]], {a, 0, n}]` with any `n`.

Comment: Of course, positive integer.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification! Using Reduce is a bit slow, though, so I guess I'll go with the series expansion suggested by user64494 and Acus